# Filtering Duplicates By Group (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, tidyverse, data-manipulation

The sample data is shown below,

1) I need to remove the people (`ID`s) who have more than one `GroupID` recored in `Month` `0`. So for example, `FGH` should not be included in my analysis.

2) I want to calculate the percent of people (unique `ID`s) who have the same `GroupID` from month 0 to month 4 consecutively (month 1, 2 and 3 and 4). (example `ID` `ABC` fits this criteria, even though they have two group IDs recorded in month 1).

(ID is actually 9 digits). Some IDs have several group ID's each month (example YUI).

```
ID   Month   GroupID
ABC   0      390988
ABC   1      390988
ABC   1      934667
ABC   2      390988
ABC   3      390988
ABC   4      390988
FGH   0      678743
FGH   0      789555
FGH   1      678666
FGH   2      678666
FGH   2      982342
YUI   0      989000
YUI   1      567099
YUI   2      873467
YUI   3      567099
YUI   3      348938
YUI   4      567099
```

I am somewhat new to R, and I am looking for a `dplyr`/ `tidyverse` solution to this seemingly easy manipulation. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`.

Comment: I've expanded the data and the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. In two steps, first problem 1 and then problem with input data the output of 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(zeros = sum(Month == 0)) %>%
  filter(zeros < 2) %>%
  select(-zeros)

df2
## A tibble: 5 x 3
## Groups:   ID [2]
#  ID    Month GroupID
#  <fct> <int>   <int>
#1 ABC       0     390
#2 ABC       1     390
#3 ABC       2     390
#4 YUI       0     989
#5 YUI       1     567
```

Now use this output as the input of the next pipe.

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(M = c(TRUE, diff(Month) == 1),
         G = GroupID[M],
         G = length(unique(G))) %>%
  filter(M & G == 1) %>%
  select(-M, -G)

df3
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   ID [1]
#  ID    Month GroupID
#  <fct> <int>   <int>
#1 ABC       0     390
#2 ABC       1     390
#3 ABC       2     390
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID   Month   GroupID
ABC   0      390
ABC   1      390
ABC   2      390 
FGH   0      678
FGH   0      789
FGH   1      678
FGH   2      678
YUI   0      989
YUI   1      567                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, the second solution does not work because the groupID I provided was only an example (it has 6 digits), whereas the ID has 9 digits. I get the following error when I run, df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(M = c(TRUE, diff(Month) == 1),
         G = GroupID[M],
         G = length(unique(G)) . "Column G must be length 6 (the group size) or one, not four"

Comment: @NewBee See my comment to the question.